# Get key and value in seperate variables in jinja

Tags: jinja2

I have a dictionary which is dynamically getting generated -

```
FullList = [1234:[{
         "Key": "CI",
          "Value": "blah"
          }
          ],
           5678:[{
         "Key": "CI",
          "Value": "blah-blah"
          }
          ]]
```

In jinja, I want 2 variables namely `x` and `y` where `x` should have value `1234` and `y` should have value `blah`.

My dictionary is forming this way and I have tried multiple attempts to form it in a different way but this is the only way I am able to form it.

Comment: "I have a **dictionary** ..." - According to the variable name - `FullList` and the outer `[]` (instead of `{}`) you have a **list**, not a dictionary. So what **actual structure type** do you have?

Comment: "I want 2 variables namely `x` and `y` where `x` should have value `1234` and `y` should have `value blah`" - Your provided an *example*, but **algorithm** of obtaining these values is not clear. Something like "I want `x` to contain a top-key in my dictionary, and want `y` to be a `Value` field in the dictionary, which in turn the top-value in my dictionary corresponding to the key `x`". In the current form, your example is fulfilled by simple (and useless) `{% set x = 1234 %}`, `{% set y = "blah" %}`. Of cource, before providing the algorithm, you should check the actual type of your data.